Eigenvalues of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} -A & A \\ A &-A \end{bmatrix}$
Currently I have observed that the eigenvalues of the matrix $\hat{A} = \begin{bmatrix} -A & A \\ A &-A \end{bmatrix}$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\sigma(A)$, which is the spectrum of $A$, are $\sigma(\hat{A})= \{-2\cdot \sigma, 0, \ldots, 0 \}$ with n zero entries.
A simple example is A=1 resulting in $\sigma(\hat{A})= \{-2,0\}$ or choosing $A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ the spectrum is $\sigma(\hat{A})= \{-2, -4,0,0\}$.
I think it should be easy to show why this happens, but at the moment I am stuck trying to prove this result. Can anyone help?

Try writing down the eigenvectors for $\hat{A}$ explicitly (depending on the eigenvectors of $A$).

look up the kronecker product and its spectral properties

@SebastianSchoennenbeck This is indeed the first idea that comes to one's mind, but it hardly reflects multiplicities.

@AnneBauval True, but I think it is still worthwhile to do because it shows a lot of what is going on.

The matrix is $\pmatrix{-1&1\\ 1&-1}\otimes A$. Since the eigenvalues of the first matrix are $-2$ and $0$, the result follows. Put it another way, as
$$
\pmatrix{1&1\\ -1&1}^{-1}\pmatrix{-1&1\\ 1&-1}\pmatrix{1&1\\ -1&1}
=\pmatrix{-2&0\\ 0&0},
$$
your block matrix is similar to
\begin{align}
&\pmatrix{I&I\\ -I&I}^{-1}\pmatrix{-A&A\\ A&-A}\pmatrix{I&I\\ -I&I}\\
&=\frac12\pmatrix{I&-I\\ I&I}\pmatrix{-A&A\\ A&-A}\pmatrix{I&I\\ -I&I}\\
&=\frac12\pmatrix{I&-I\\ I&I}\pmatrix{-2A&0\\ 2A&0}\\
&=\pmatrix{-2A&0\\ 0&0}.\\
\end{align}
Hence its spectrum consists of $-2$ times each eigenvalue of $A$ as well as $n$ copies of zero.

From this Wikipedia page,
$$\begin{align}\det\begin{pmatrix}-A-tI_n&A\\A&-A-tI_n\end{pmatrix}&=\det\left((-A-tI_n)^2-A^2\right)\\&=\det\left(2tA+t^2I_n\right)\\&=t^n\det\left(2A+tI_n\right).\end{align}$$
